# Strategy pattern using Enums. Need a simple example in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, enums, strategy-pattern

I'm trying to understand the strategy pattern and enums in java. I've googled this and have found a few articles on the subject, but most of them seemed too complex for my understanding. Could anyone provide a simple example or another link that demonstrates strategy pattern using enums in laymen terms using java?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Asking for external resources is off-topic. Why does the example have to apply to enums? The strategy pattern is completely independent of enums. Do you understand the pattern itself? Do you understand what an enum is?

Comment: I think below is an awesome example and works perfectly for what I was looking for!!! Thanks. I wanted an enum example. Not an overly verbose class filled example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do:

```
interface Strategy {

    int execute(int a, int b);
}

enum Math implements Strategy {

    Add {

                @Override
                public int execute(int a, int b) {
                    return a + b;
                }
            },
    Subtract {

                @Override
                public int execute(int a, int b) {
                    return a - b;
                }
            },
    Multiply {

                @Override
                public int execute(int a, int b) {
                    return a * b;
                }
            };
}
```

It is a re-implementation of the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) using `enum` for the strategies.

Or a little longer but more clearly a strategy pattern:

```
public interface FailureStrategy {
    void fail (String message);
}

enum Failure implements FailureStrategy {
    Ignore {

        @Override
        public void fail(String message) {
            // Do nothing on success.
        }

    },
    LogToConsole {

        @Override
        public void fail(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }

    },
    ErrToConsole {

        @Override
        public void fail(String message) {
            System.err.println(message);
        }

    },
    RingAlarmBells {

        @Override
        public void fail(String message) {
            // Left to the student.
        }

    },
    SoundTheKlaxon {

        @Override
        public void fail(String message) {
            // Left to the student.
        }

    },
    EndTheWorld {

        @Override
        public void fail(String message) {
            // Left to the student.
        }

    };
}

public class SomethingLethal {
    public FailureStrategy onFail = Failure.EndTheWorld;
}

public class SomethingDangerous {
    public FailureStrategy onFail = Failure.RingAlarmBells;
}

public class SomethingBenign {
    public FailureStrategy onFail = Failure.Ignore;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Without the interface, and having a (3 times ovverriden) base function `int execute(int a, int b)` one already could call this a strategy pattern, nicely compact.

Comment: Note: enum constants should be all capital case.

Comment: @Puce - I never let dogma get in the way of readability. :)

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon That's OK. But do you think e.g. `LogToConsole` is easier to read and to be recognized as a constant than `LOG_TO_CONSOLE`?

Comment: @Puce - My IDE knows it as a constant and colours it for me to remind me. I don't need to mangle my code to support an archaic and IMHO bad naming convention. A wise man understands the difference between a dogma and a mantra. :) I'm not going to shout in my code just to adhere to a coding standard.

Comment: No need to create a new interface. You can create a abstract method in enum, like this:

abstract int execute(int a, int b);

Comment: @Wendel - True, but exposing only the `interface` reduces the overall exposure to a minimum which is usually a good idea. The alternative would be to expose the whole `Enum` which would allow users to take liberties, which, of course, they will.